# Why won't my USB headset work OTG with my Honor 6x?

Tags: usb, audio, usb-on-the-go

I'm using an Honor 6x running EMUI 5.0. I bought an OTG cable recently, a female USB to male Micro-USB to use with this phone. I've connected a mouse and keyboard, and those worked fine. But, when I connect my Razer Kraken 7.1 USB headset, I get no audio or any sign a device is even connected. Is there a way to get my headset to work?

Answer (score 0):

The lack of answer suggests this probably isn't worth pursuing, it probably depends upon phone, headset, and operating system. Another way this works out is with my LG G3 phone, Logitech A-0374A USB headset, and Android 6, with OTG cable: I get media sound through the headphone, but on phone calls neither the headphone nor the microphone is recognised, the phone's speaker and mic are used instead. I've looked at a couple of other places where this is discussed, with no resolution.